# Coloring a circle (sprite/image or mesh ) in a circular fashion starting in the middle till the required radius

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create this kind of tunneling effect in which a  little circles of different radius are shown inside of another circle and i want to make color shift between them seemlessly from one inner circle to other outer circle.

I have tried placing 4 circles under a common object and changing there materialcolor (4circles as images in canvas, sprite and model from blender as well. I need a good direction .I have created a texture to use as in with setPixel() i have made to work it with full radius . as SetPixel takes integer. In my mind i think the solution lies in the fact either i need a circluar lines that can fill up the thing gradually or little area fills for circle .  I'm ready to work with shaders or any other approach as necessary.
code sample : Here circlesContainer contains many such circles and each circle contain 4 circles with 0 index as smallest circle inside the bigger one.

```
 public IEnumerator TunnelingColors( float delayTime,Transform circlesContainer)
{
     currentColor = (Color)CircleColorsList [UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, CircleColors.Length)];

    for (int i = 0; i < circlesContainer.transform.childCount; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.childCount; j++) {


                    circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (j).GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = currentColor;


        }
    }

    while (true)
    {
[UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, CircleColors.Length)];
             smallestCirclecolor = (Color)CircleColorsList [UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, CircleColors.Length)];
             smallerCirclecolor = (Color)CircleColorsList [UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, CircleColors.Length)];
             smallCirclecolor = (Color)CircleColorsList [UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, CircleColors.Length)];
             Circlecolor = (Color)CircleColorsList [UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, CircleColors.Length)];

        for(   t = 0 ; t <= delayTime ; t += 1f )
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f);

            if (t > 1f && t <= 3f) {

                for (int i = 0; i < circlesContainer.transform.childCount; i++) {



                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = smallestCirclecolor;



                }

            } else if (t >= 3f && t <= 5f) {

                for (int i = 0; i < circlesContainer.transform.childCount; i++) {


                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = smallerCirclecolor;


                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (1).GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = smallestCirclecolor;



                }

            } else if (t > 5f && t <=6f) {
                for (int i = 0; i < circlesContainer.transform.childCount; i++) {


                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = smallCirclecolor;


                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (1).GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = smallerCirclecolor;



                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (2).GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = smallestCirclecolor;




                }  

            } else if (t > 6f&&t<=7f) {
                for (int i = 0; i < circlesContainer.transform.childCount; i++) {


                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = smallCirclecolor;



                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (1).GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = smallCirclecolor;



                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (2).GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = smallerCirclecolor;



                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (3).GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = smallestCirclecolor;


                }


            }else if (t > 7f && t<= 8f) {
                for (int i = 0; i < circlesContainer.transform.childCount; i++) {


                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = smallCirclecolor;



                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (1).GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = smallCirclecolor;



                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (2).GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = smallCirclecolor;


                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (3).GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = smallerCirclecolor;

                }


            }else if (t > 8f ) {
                for (int i = 0; i < circlesContainer.transform.childCount; i++) {


                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = smallCirclecolor;



                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (1).GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = smallCirclecolor;
                        }


                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (2).GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = smallCirclecolor;
                        }

                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (3).GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = smallCirclecolor;
                        }
                        currentColor = smallCirclecolor;

                }


            }


        }



        yield return null ;
    }


}
```

and i have tried lerping the colors like in first case

```
circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material.color = smallestCirclecolor;
                            Color.Lerp(currentcolor,smallestCircleColor,t/delaytime);
```

Results with lerping.
little video : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7LoX90Lc4O2OTJRNGhGLWpfY0k/view?usp=sharing

EDIT:
@mgear Here is the updated code and the associated video i'm having some doubts here.

```
 public IEnumerator TunnelingColorsMaterial ( float delayTime,Transform circlesContainer)
    {

        currentColor = (Color)CircleColorsList [UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, CircleColors.Length)];

        for (int i = 0; i < circlesContainer.transform.childCount; i++) {


            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = currentColor;
            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (1).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = currentColor;          
            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (2).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = currentColor;
            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (3).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = currentColor;
            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (4).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = currentColor;


        }


        while (true) {
            smallestCirclecolor = (Color)CircleColorsList [UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, CircleColors.Length)];
            smallerCirclecolor = (Color)CircleColorsList [UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, CircleColors.Length)];
            smallCirclecolor = (Color)CircleColorsList [UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, CircleColors.Length)];
            Circlecolor = (Color)CircleColorsList [UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, CircleColors.Length)];

            for (t = 0; t <= delayTime; t += 0.01f) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.01f);

                for (int i = 0; i < circlesContainer.transform.childCount; i++) {


                    circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).localScale = Vector3.Lerp (circlesContainer.GetChild (0).transform.GetChild (0).localScale, new Vector3 (circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforSmallestCircle, circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforSmallestCircle, circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforSmallestCircle), t / 0.5f);
                    circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (1).localScale = Vector3.Lerp (circlesContainer.GetChild (0).transform.GetChild (1).localScale, new Vector3 (circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforSmallCircle, circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforSmallCircle, circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforSmallCircle), t / 1f);
                    circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (2).localScale = Vector3.Lerp (circlesContainer.GetChild (0).transform.GetChild (2).localScale, new Vector3 (circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforLargeCircle, circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforLargeCircle, circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforLargeCircle), t / 1.5f);
                    circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (3).localScale = Vector3.Lerp (circlesContainer.GetChild (0).transform.GetChild (3).localScale, new Vector3 (circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforLargestCircle, circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforLargestCircle, circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforLargestCircle), t / 2f);

                    if (circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).localScale.x == circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforSmallestCircle) {


                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = Color.Lerp(currentColor,smallestCirclecolor,t);
                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (1).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = currentColor;

                    }


                    if (circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (1).localScale.x == circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforSmallCircle) {



                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = Color.Lerp(smallestCirclecolor,smallerCirclecolor,t);
                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (1).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = Color.Lerp(currentColor,smallestCirclecolor,t);
                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (2).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = currentColor;

                    }

                    if (circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (2).localScale.x == circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforLargeCircle) {

                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = Color.Lerp(smallerCirclecolor,smallCirclecolor,t);
                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (1).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = Color.Lerp(smallestCirclecolor,smallerCirclecolor,t);
                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (2).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = Color.Lerp(currentColor,smallestCirclecolor,t);

                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (3).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = currentColor;


                    }

                    if (circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (3).localScale.x == circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforLargestCircle) {

                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = Color.Lerp(smallerCirclecolor,smallCirclecolor,t);
                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (1).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = Color.Lerp(smallerCirclecolor,smallCirclecolor,t);
                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (2).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = Color.Lerp(smallestCirclecolor,smallerCirclecolor,t);

                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (3).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = Color.Lerp(currentColor,smallestCirclecolor,t);
                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).localScale = Vector3.Lerp (circlesContainer.GetChild (0).transform.GetChild (0).localScale, new Vector3 (circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforSmallCircle, circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforSmallCircle, circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforSmallCircle), t / 0.5f);


                    }
                    if (circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).localScale.x == circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforSmallCircle) {

                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color =  Color.Lerp(smallerCirclecolor,smallCirclecolor,t);
                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (1).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color =  Color.Lerp(smallerCirclecolor,smallCirclecolor,t);
                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (2).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = Color.Lerp(smallerCirclecolor,smallCirclecolor,t);
                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (3).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = Color.Lerp(smallestCirclecolor,smallerCirclecolor,t);
                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).localScale = Vector3.Lerp (circlesContainer.GetChild (0).transform.GetChild (0).localScale, new Vector3 (circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforLargeCircle, circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforLargeCircle, circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforLargeCircle), t / 0.5f);



                    }

                    if (circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).localScale.x == circleDiameterRequiredInInchesforLargeCircle) {

                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color =  Color.Lerp(smallerCirclecolor,smallCirclecolor,t);
                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (1).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color =  Color.Lerp(smallerCirclecolor,smallCirclecolor,t);
                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (2).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = Color.Lerp(smallerCirclecolor,smallCirclecolor,t);
                        circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (3).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = Color.Lerp (smallerCirclecolor, smallCirclecolor, t);
        //              circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (4).GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = Color.Lerp (currentColor, smallCirclecolor, t);

                    }












        }

            }






            for (int i = 0; i < circlesContainer.transform.childCount; i++) {
                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (0).localScale = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (1).localScale = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (2).localScale = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
                            circlesContainer.GetChild (i).transform.GetChild (3).localScale = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);

                        }



            yield return null;
        }


    }
```

If I have the only commented line in the code what i have is the color stays up for so long and if i don't have that line there is sudden change of all colours . 
What i want to have is to have a same color and start the colouring again in similar fashion , i 'm not good with Lerping and getting a feeling that the last parameter is the one which is causing the color to stay .

Here is the video in which the last color is staying.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7LoX90Lc4O2czlWMldCMUpFYTg

Comment: Nice idea, but what have you tried? Also, where is your question?

Comment: I have tried placing 4 circles under a common object and changing there materialcolor (4circles as images in canvas, sprite and model from blender as well. I need a good direction .I have created a texture to use as in with setPixel() i have made to work it with full radius . as SetPixel takes int.

Comment: Please add this detail to your question, show your code, show the result, and also describe what is your goal, and how the result is not fulfilling that. Please read about [what questions are suitable on this site, and how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Please add clear details and references to what you have done, and where are you stuck.

Comment: A great solution here is particles.

3D engines are just not made for rendering flat color shapes. They are ridiculously bad at doing that.

As the Unity manual explains, you just can not do "stuff like that" using mainstream 3D technology: this is why particles" exist.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ParticleSystems.html

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/14325

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would need to see example image of what you want to archieve..

But still there area many options:

- Use multiple overlapping sprites and scale them (can adjust tint color for each sprite)
- Generate circular mesh with vertex colors (can adjust colors from script or using shader, or textures/mask textures. See Google [Cardboard reticle](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/blob/master/GoogleVR/Scripts/UI/GvrReticle.cs) as an circular mesh generation example)
- Use shaders (example image below is just a quad mesh and uses [this shader](https://github.com/UnityCommunity/UnityLibrary/blob/master/Shaders/Effects/2D/ExplosionCircle.shader))

[image: CircularShader]

Comment: regarding your first point scaling them , i have tried it with animation will i be able to control the scale in animation through code or should i like change the scale in coroutine or update types.

Comment: well test it just from script first in Update() loop, easier.

Comment: can you check where i'm making a mistake .

Comment: Didn't try the code, but if the problem is sorting order, set sprite Order in layer (lower value is behind)

Comment: the first two suggestions are not practical.  Yes, you can do it with a shader for sure.  that's a nice link too.

Comment: I would actually just delete your first two suggestions here, @mgear. ROck on.